# Visual studio 2015 - can't open new project window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015, i needed to create a visual c++ projet, i opened the new project window normally, and than i downloaded the requirements. after all is done, and both Virtual studio and the pc restarted, Whenever i click "New Project..." on the start page i get this error :

> new project i get this error : new project/item dialog could not be
>   initialized due to error: could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationInsights, Version=3.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image: Can't open a new project Error]
Any ideas about what caused the problem ? any solutions ?

Comment: Repair vs , maybe this work .